# Deserializing and byteswapping 48-bit integers

Tags: c++, deserialization, endianness

I am receiving packets off the network so they are in big-endian byte order and I need to deserialize them then convert them to little-endian byte order for x86.

This is straightforward for standard C/C++ types such as `foo` below, but what should I do if the packet contains a 6-byte integer `bar`?

Should I just use a `pragma pack(1)` with 48-bit bit-field?

```
#include <byteswap.h>

#pragma pack (push, 1)
typedef struct MyFooBar {
    uint64_t foo;
    uint64_t bar : 48;

    void off_wire() {
        foo = bswap_64(foo);
        //bar = bswap_48(bar); 
    }
} MyFooBar;
#pragma pack (pop)
```

What's a fast implementation of `bswap_48`? Is this correct?

```
typedef uint64_t uint48_t;

uint48_t bswap_48(uint48_t x) {
    return ((((x) & 0x0000000000ff) << 40) |    \
            (((x) & 0x00000000ff00) << 24) |    \
            (((x) & 0x000000ff0000) << 8)  |    \
            (((x) & 0x0000ff000000) >> 8)  |    \
            (((x) & 0x00ff00000000) >> 24) |    \
            (((x) & 0xff0000000000) >> 40));
}
```

Comment: You could read it into a 64bit variable, swap and shift by 16 bits?

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen Is my above implementation correct?

Comment: The `uintNN_t` names are reserved for compiler , you should use a different name

Comment: apart from that, the `bswap_48` looks correct